# PendingIntent Broadcast is always running after upgrading to API 31

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-pendingintent

The BroadcastReceiver was working perfectly in targetSdkVersion 30. After upgrading to 31, I added PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE then the Broadcast is always running even though I change the CODE and it can't be cancelled.

Code:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, FetchDataReceiver.class);

    final int isAlarmUpFlag = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S ?
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE: PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE;
    boolean isAlarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, MY_CODE,
            myIntent,  isAlarmUpFlag) != null);
```

isAlarmUp is always TRUE.

Comment: I do not know if you need `FLAG_MUTABLE` in that particular bit of code. "the Broadcast is always running" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: isAlarmUp is always TRUE even though I install the app on a brand new emulator.

Comment: Tried FLAG_IMMUTABLE, same issue.

Comment: I meant just using `FLAG_NO_CREATE`.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code you use to create the `PendingIntent` in the first place.

Comment: Did you try @CommonsWare suggestion and remove `FLAG_MUTABLE`?

Comment: Only using FLAG_NO_CREATE will get this error. Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code you use to create the `PendingIntent`.